# Differences in reading binary files between R and python

Tags: python, r, binary

I have a binary file and I know the first 3 bytes should be 0x6c, 0x1b, and 0x01, in that order.
I used python and R to load the file.

Python:

`f = open('pathToFile', 'rb')
f.read(3)`

I get: `out[2] b'l\x1b\x01'`

While in R:

`readBin('pathToFile', what='raw', n=3)`

I get `[1] 6c 1b 01`

I do not understand this `b'l'` in the python output, since I am expecting `6c` (as the R output shows).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So binary values are just numbers. Use `list(f.read(3))` to see that in python. R and Python just use two different representations by default. R uses [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) and Python uses [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) (with `\xhh` for non-ascii values). The reason for this difference is that Python is a general purpose language and many (normally old but also not) terminals and programs use 7-bit ascii to display output. R ignores this usage as it's normally only interested in raw data.

To get the hexadecimal representation in python, use this `bytes` subclass

```
class BytesHex(bytes):
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' '.join('{:0>2x}'.format(b) for b in self)

BytesHex(b'l\x1b\x01')
Out[158]: 6c 1b 01
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explains a lot. I just noticed I can quickly convert this as well with `f.read(3).hex()` as well.

Comment: Well you taught me something. Didn't even know that method existed!